# convert "Table" to "data.frame"

Tags: r

I want to covert count.table (class = "table") to data.frame

```
> count.table
         High  Low  Mid None
   P2-1   198   41   35  160
   P2-2   179   49   41  165
   P2-3   184   45   24  181
   P2-4   181   43   29  181
   P3-1    64   70   13  280
   P3-2    87   79   24  244
   P3-3    60   84   13  277
   P3-4   108   60   22  244
   P3-5    87   65   19  263
```

I used:

```
count.df <- as.data.frame.matrix(count.table)
```

But the problem is in count.df the variable name for the first column is set as "row.names".

see:

```
> names(count.df)
[1] "High" "Low"  "Mid"  "None"
```

Question: How to assign a variable name for the first column? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create it :

```
count.df$var_names <- row.names(count.df)
```

If you want it as the first column:

```
cbind.data.frame(var_names=row.names(count.df),count.df)
```

Comment: You can do the whole thing in one go `as.data.frame.matrix(cbind(var_names = row.names(count.table), count.table))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, slight difference, but I think you meant: `cbind(var_names = row.names(count.table), as.data.frame.matrix(count.table))`.